# Propensity score matching: Select relevant covariats with regression?

Tags: probability

I‘m performing a propensity score matching in a health economics setting. The goal is to show the effect of a certain treatment on health expenses. Is it reasonable to identify first the covariats with the highest impact on health expenses? A matching for covariats that don't influence expenses is worthless, isn't it? What do you think?

Comment: what is a covariat ?

Comment: A covariant? A co-variate?... @JeanMarie

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariate